# What is the fully-qualified namespace with the assembly name called?

Tags: c#

This is the Fully-Qualified Namespace of a class Bla:

```
"System.Exception.Bla";
```

This is:

```
 "System.Exception.Bla, Company.Services";
```

What do you call the above string?

Comment: Do you mean, how to access a class in a foreign assembly?

Comment: What code have you tried, and what are you trying to call?

Comment: More approprate FQN would be `global::System.Exception.Bla`. As the string I call just string, sometimes char sequence. ;-).

Comment: @JamesKyburz, "call" in sense of naming convention I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assembly-qualified name.

Please note that you use partial assembly name.